# Kähler geometry: coefficient 1/2 of the Kähler form and the sign of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I’m studying Kähler geometry.
I have several quiet basic questions:

1. The Kähler metric is usually denoted by $g_{\mathbb{C}}=\sum _{i,j}g_{i\bar{j}}dz^i\otimes d\bar{z}^j$, Kähler form is defined to be $\omega(\cdot,\cdot)=g(J\cdot,\cdot)$. However, many materials, like in Yau’s proof to Calabi conjecture and Gang Tian’s book Canonical metrics in Kähler geometry, $\omega=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2}g_{i\bar{j}}dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^j$.

Here is what confusing me: $g_\mathbb{C}=g_{i\bar{j}}dz^i\otimes d\bar{z}^j + g_{j\bar{i}}d\bar{z}^i\otimes dz^j$ then, $\omega= \sqrt{-1}g_{i\bar{j}}dz^i\otimes d\bar{z}^j -\sqrt{-1}g_{j\bar{i}}d\bar{z}^i\otimes dz^j=\sqrt{-1}g_{i\bar{j}}(dz^i\otimes d\bar{z}^j -d\bar{z}^j\otimes dz^i)= \sqrt{-1}g_{i\bar{j}}dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^j $, always missing $\frac{1}{2}$.

I have the following attempts:

(1) John Lee’s Smooth manifold page 358 says there are two different conventions of wedge. If $dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^j=\frac{1}{2}(dz^i\otimes d\bar{z}^j -d\bar{z}^j\otimes dz^i)$, the coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$ does exist;

(2) $dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^j$ still defined to be $dz^i\otimes d\bar{z}^j -d\bar{z}^j\otimes dz^i$, however the convention $g_{\mathbb{C}}$ stands for $\frac{1}{2}g_{i\bar{j}}dz^i\otimes d\bar{z}^j + \frac{1}{2}g_{j\bar{i}}d\bar{z}^i\otimes dz^j$.

$\textbf{My frist question:}$ does (1) and (2) makes sense? or it really doesn’t matter.

2. I’m following Tian’s book to compute the curvature tensor from $\mathbb{C}$-extending the real case:
   $R(u,v)w=\nabla_u\nabla_vw-\nabla_v\nabla_uw-\nabla_{[u,v]}w$, and $R(u,v,w,z)=g_{\mathbb{C}}(R(u,v)z,w)$, where $u,v, w,z\in T_\mathbb{C}M$:
   $R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}}:=R(\partial_i,\partial_\bar{j}, \partial_k,\partial_\bar{l})=g_{\mathbb{C}}(\nabla_i\nabla_\bar{j}\partial_\bar{l},\partial_k)=g_\mathbb{C}(\nabla_i(g^{q\bar{p}}g_{q\bar{j},\bar{l}}\partial_\bar{p}),\partial_k)=g_{\mathbb{C}}(g^{q\bar{p}}g_{q\bar{j},i\bar{l}}\partial_\bar{p}-g^{q\bar{r}}g_{s\bar{r},i}g^{s\bar{p}}g_{q\bar{j},\bar{l}}\partial_\bar{p},\partial_k)=g_{k\bar{j},i\bar{l}}-g^{q\bar{r}}g_{k\bar{r},i}g_{q\bar{j},\bar{l}}$, in my computation, the sign of second order term now is positive, it’s wrong.

Here is what I thought:

(1) most books define the postion to raise or lower to be the second or the fourth, in this way, I can get the right sign. However I don’t see why this corresponds to the real case.

$\textbf{My second question:}$ is my computation wrong? or the Tian’s book is wrong? or there is some definition difference I didn’t notice.

$\textbf{My third question:}$ is it true $R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}}=-R_{\bar{j}ik\bar{l}}$ & $R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}}=-R_{\bar{j}ik\bar{l}}$? I don’t see any difference from the real case, however I can’t remember from where I read it lost antisymmetry in the first and second, third and fourth position. I want to make sure of it.

Thanks!

Comment: That's too many questions, and your second and third questions have not much to do with the first one. Please ask two separate questions.

Comment: The factor of $\sqrt{-1}/2$ has nothing to do with conventions on wedge product. It's there because $dz\wedge d\bar z = -2\sqrt{-1}dx\wedge dy$, so we multiply by the factor to get the standard area form on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Remember that for a hermitian connection, the curvature matrix $(\Omega_{i\bar j})$ is skew-hermitian. We write $\Omega_{i\bar j} = \sum R_{i\bar jk\bar\ell} dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j\wedge dz^k\wedge d\bar z^\ell$ (with or without a factor of $1/2$). Your equations seem wrong because you're missing conjugation, but also because when you switch $i$ and $j$, the bar on the subscript should stay on the second slot. Conjugating $R$, as you should, will make everything consistent.

Comment: @TedShifrin Great, then 1.(2) is consistent with $\mathbb{C}^n$, question 1 will not bother me. I think Question 2 also doesn’t matter now, I can change the contracted slot in Ricci & sectional curvature to make sure sphere has positive curvature.  The last one, you mean $\overline{R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}}}=R_{j\bar{i}l\bar{k}}$, it’s true, yet I want to change the position of bar. Thank you, prof., these questions bother me for weeks. Also this drives me to wonder, can the curvature of a complex manifold to be a complex number?

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by your last question.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sure, I wondered, for kaehler manifold, is its $R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}}$ must be a real number for every $i,j,k,l$. Here is what I thought these days: it is possible, since $R$ is obtained by $\mathbb{C}$-extension of the real Riemann curvature, we still have $\bar{R}=R$. Because the basis $dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^j\wedge dz^k\wedge d\bar{z}^l$ is not real, I cannot expect the corresponding coefficient $R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}}$ to always be real.

Comment: You should be thinking about sectional curvatures and holomorphic sectional curvatures, not individual coefficients.